# How to write a privacy policy for an app

Tags: ios, privacy, privacy-policy

I'm trying to submit my app to the app store and it seems I have to write a privacy policy. I don't know where to start. 
My app uses Firebase to store info (profile info) and to run a chat between the users. It's free and I don't have adds...
I'm developing it for a company.

Is there any free tool or something? I can't believe that every developer that submit an app knows how to do this, it has to be some guide to make it easier...

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a privacy policy in itself is not programming related.

Comment: If you are developing it for a company then it is their responsibility to `1)` take legal advice and `2)` to create a privacy policy valid for each country that the app will sell in.

Comment: Hey Jaime, as you can see these kinds of questions get flagged rather fast on SO. I'm linking you to one [related answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-a-mobile-app-privacy-policy/answer/Simon-Schmid) I've given on Quora that will surely help. If it doesn't include everything you need to know, just find my other posts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not programming related but I have done something similar a while ago. You can not take this word to word, you need legal advice.

But you can use https://www.eula.io/ and their sdk.

Follow this tutorial on github. https://github.com/AdamBCo/eula-ios-sdk

You should end up something like

[image]